# Bootstrap 3 navbar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put the height of the navigation bar at 40px, but when I put it and i resize the web page the dropdown menu doesn't work properly.
Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="barranavegacion">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white; font-size: 16pt"">Gangatravel               
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a id="texto" href="http://vuelos.gangatravel.es/" target="_blank">Vuelos</a></li>
        <li><a id="texto" href="http://hoteles.gangatravel.es/" target="_blank">Hoteles</a></li>
        <li><a id="texto" href="#">Coches</a></li>
        <li><a id="texto" href="http://rutas.gangatravel.es/es/s/" target="_blank">Rutas</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.es/"><img style="max-width: 30px; max-height: 30px; margin-top: -12px;" src="IMAGENES/youtube2.png"/></a></li>  
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.es/"><img style="max-width: 30px; max-height: 30px; margin-top: -12px;" src="IMAGENES/twitter2.png"/></a></li>  
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.es/"><img style="max-width: 30px; max-height: 30px; margin-top: -12px;" src="IMAGENES/facebook2.png"/></a></li>    
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/"><img style="max-width: 30px; max-height: 30px; margin-top: -12px;" src="IMAGENES/google.png"/></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>

#barranavegacion{
background-color:#333; 
border: none;   
height: 40px;}
```

Comment: *dropdown menu doesn't work properly.* Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Check it http://gangatravel.esy.es/ resize the web page and click on the dropdown menu. Without the height:40px i can see the dropdown menu in background-color:#333;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with your HTML `<a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white; font-size: 16pt"">Gangatravel</a>` has additional `"`

Bootstrap uses responsive design.You changed globally the height of the menu, when you should had only for some screen sizes using `@media` css query

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/kaohLdyg/